# Kahler identities on symplectic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In Hutchings and Taubes's lecture note on Seiberg-Witten equation, a Weitzenbock formula is given, and the authors state that the Weitzenbock formula, proven in Donaldson's book using Kahler identities
\begin{equation}
    {\bar \partial ^*} = i\Lambda \partial , \;\;\;\;\text{etc}
\end{equation}
are actually valid on a symplectic manifold with an adapted almost hermitian structure. Namely, it seems that Kahler identities do not require integrability of the almost complex structure.

I know the proof of Kahler identities on a Kahler manifold $X$: one first does it on $\mathbb{C}^2$, then choose a nice holomorphic coordinate on $X$, such that the metric $g$ on $X$ is just the Euclidean metric with $O(\Delta x^2)$ errors.

So I wonder:

Is there a similar trick (choosing a nice $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ frame?) for a symplectic manifold to prove Kahler identities? Any reference on how to actually prove them?

Comment: I think you want the Kähler identity you wrote to say $\bar{\partial}^* = i[\Lambda, \partial]$ (up to sign), i.e. there is one more term involved. A symplectic manifold with an adapted hermitian structure is also known as an "almost Kähler manifold"; see this preprint by Cirici and Wilson https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01414, Prop 3.1. for a list of "almost Kähler identities". The operators $\bar{\mu}$ and $\mu$ that show up are the additional graded pieces of the complexified exterior derivative that you have on an almost complex manifold.